# Examples of series approximating $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

The first time I saw this serie is in an article titled “Examples of series approximating $\pi$”. It was said that the most beautiful formula among a lot is this:

$$\pi=\frac{9801}{2\sqrt{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(4n)!}{(n!)^{4}}\frac{1103+26390n}{396^{4n}}}$$ by Ramanujan.

My question is what makes this formula so beautiful?

Comment: It is inscrutable!  That is, how did Ramanujan come up with something like this?

Comment: The first term in the series is within 0.0000025% of $\pi$.

Comment: Is there a proof that this formula's limit is $\pi$? I heard that Ramanujan liked to write down correct formulas without proofs.

Comment: @LeifSabellek yeah, proposed in $1910$ and proved in $1985$ by Borwein brothers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Beauty" could mean the fact that there is no reason why the combination of numbers put forth should ever be seen to have anything to do with $\pi$ by mere mortals.  Or the fact that the series converges so damn quickly.

Comment: I don't think it converges that fast, does it?  It looks like that summand is approximately a geometric series.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: it does...but the $n$th term is approx $C n^{-1/2} (99)^{-4 n}$ for large $n$, where $C=2 (2 \pi)^{-3/2} 26390$.  Each term is almost $10^8$ smaller than the previous one.  To me, that's pretty good.

Comment: Fair enough.  But my idea of rapid convergence is where each extra term doubles the number of digits.  I think Ramanujun has an iterative method that does that.

Answer (score 2):

The following *Wikipedia* articles and paragraphs are relevant to your question:

- [Approximations of π : 20<sup>th</sup> Century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_Pi#20th_century)
- [Chudnovsky Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm)
- [List of Formulae Involving π : Efficient Infinite Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_Pi#Efficient_infinite_series)
- [List of Formulae Involving π : Other Infinite Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_Pi#Infinite_series)

Comment: It seems those links are at best loosely related to OP's question.

Comment: Why ? In what way ? I don't understand.